# Biopython blast parameters for short nucleotidic sequences

Tags: python, biopython, blast, ncbi

I am trying to run blastn through biopython with NCBIWWW.
I am using the qblast function on a given sample file.
I have a few methods defined and everything works like a charm when my fasta contains sequences that are long enough. The only case where it fails it is when I need to blast reads coming from Illumina sequencing that are too short. So I would say it is probably due to the fact that there no automatic redefinition of blasting parameters when submitting the work.

I tried everything I could to come close to blastn-short conditions (see table C2 from [here](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK1763/)) without any success.

It looks like I am not capable to feed in the correct parameters.

The closer I think I came to working situation is with the following :

```
result_handle = NCBIWWW.qblast("blastn", "nr",
                                fastaSequence,
                                word_size=7,
                                gapcosts='5 2',
                                nucl_reward=1,
                                nucl_penalty='-3',
                                expect=1000)
```

Thank you for any tip / advice to make it work.

My sample fasta read is the following one :

```
>TEST 1-211670
AGACTGCGATCCGAACTGAGAAC
```

The error that I get is the following one :

```
>ValueError: Error message from NCBI: Message ID#24 Error: Failed to read the Blast query: Protein FASTA provided for nucleotide sequence
```

And when I look at [this page](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/staff/tao/URLAPI/new/node98.html), it seems that my problem is about fixing the threshold but obviously I didn't manage to make it work so far.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Why don't you put this question on bioinformatics.stackexchange?

Answer (score 0):

Once I had problems with blasting peptides and it appeared that it was an issue of proper parameters selection. It took me terribly long time to find out what they actually should be (inconsistent and scarce data on various websites including quite convoluted in this aspect NCBI documentation). I know you are interested in blasting nucleotide sequences but supposedly you will find your solution whilst having a look on the code below. Pay attention especially to params as `filter`, `composition_based_statistics`, `word_size` and `matrix_name`. In my case they appeared to be crucial.

```
blast_handle = NCBIWWW.qblast("blastp", "nr",
                              peptide_seq,
                              expect=200000.0,
                              filter=False,
                              word_size=2,
                              composition_based_statistics=False,
                              matrix_name="PAM30",
                              gapcosts="9 1",
                              hitlist_size=1000)
```

Comment: Thank for your help. As far as I know, matrix type applies only when proteins are aligned; for `word_size` I should have the proper one (from documentation), and `composition_based_statistics` and `filter` I have no idea. I tried both but none seems to help..

Answer (score 0):

This code works for me (Biopython 1.64):

```
from Bio.Blast import NCBIWWW

fastaSequence = ">TEST 1-211670\nAGACTGCGATCCGAACTGAGAAC"

result_handle = NCBIWWW.qblast("blastn", "nr",
                               fastaSequence,
                               word_size=7,
                               gapcosts='5 2',
                               nucl_reward=1,
                               nucl_penalty='-3',
                               expect=1000)

print result_handle.getvalue()
```

Maybe you are passing a wrong fastaSequence. Biopython doesn't make any transformation from SeqRecords (or anything) to plain FASTA. You have to provide the query as shown above.

Blast determines if a sequence is a nucleotide or a protein reading the first few chars. If they are in the "ACGT" above a threshold, it's a nucleotide, otherwise it's a protein. Thus your sequence is at a 100% threshold of "ACGT", impossible to be interpreted as a protein.